# $M_{R^n}$; how to derive $n$ for transitive closure?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, relations

When finding the transitive closure of a relation $R$, I convert $R$ into a boolean matrix $M_R$, and find the union between $M_R$ and its powers up to $n$.

$$M_{R^*} = M_{R^1} \lor M_{R^2} \lor \cdots \lor M_{R^n}$$

But, what is $n$ in this case?

$$M_R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

To find the transitive closure of this matrix, I would perform $M_R \lor M_{R^2} \lor M_{R^3}$, which yields the matrix:

$$M_{R^*} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

But this is just an example I read. I'm not sure why $n$ in this case is 3, but for some other transitive closures it's 5, or 6, or 2, etc. Given a relation, how do I calculate $n$?

**Update**

Upon further reading, it looks like $n$ is the number of elements in the relation, but in some of the examples I have, some relations of size $5$ for example, only compute $M_{R^*}$ up to the $4th$ power. Is there some exclusivity principle depending on the relation? Here's an example:

$$R_1 = \{(a,c),(b,d),(c,a),(d,b),(e,d)\} \text{ on } \{a,b,c,d,e\}\\
R_2 = \{(b,c),(b,e),(c,e),(d,a),(e,b),(e,c)\} \text{ on } \{a,b,c,d,e\}$$

Why is $n = 4$ for $R_1$, but $n = 5$ for $R_2$ provided both relations are working with five elements?

Comment: If you write either "\text{...}" or "..." instead of \ldots or \cdots while using TeX or LaTeX in the usual way (as opposed to the way MathJax is used on web sites) then you'll see things like $\displaystyle a{...}b$ instead of $\displaystyle a\ldots b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, cheers for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate the transitive closure there is a certain moment that you cannot add anything else (in the worst case this happens when every pair is related). The $n$ is simply the number of 'generations' you need to stabilize the exclusive or.

Comment: There is no way to infer $n$ from how the relation looks?

Comment: Doing the matrix operations IS a way to determine $n$ by 'looking at the relation'.
I am not aware of any smarter or more efficient way to do it.